# Want to declare a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, computer-science

I want to get the value of "weight" and multiply it by .38, essentially assigning that to a variable named x. However, execution says

"line 12, in 
print("On Mars you would weigh " + x + " pounds. \n"
NameError: name 'x' is not defined"

what can I do?

```
def weight_for_binky(x):
#asking for weight
    weight = int(input("What do you weigh? "))

#binky weight
    x = (weight * 0.38)

print("you weigh " + x + " pounds. \n")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    weight_for_binky(x)
```

*changed names of variables for privacy*

Comment: Presumably that print should be *inside* the function.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. In Python, how deep you indent your code means something, the print statement isn't indented to be part of the function body.

Comment: Why do you want to use x as a parameter for the function?

Comment: Even if there are already answers it would help to exactly know what you expect as a result. Is it a print out on terminal or do you need to use the calculated value later on?

Answer (score 1):

Your code has number if issues:

1. Your function has`x` parameter, but it never use it in calculations. instead you assign result of calculations to `x`
2. That `x` is in local scope of the function and is not available outside the function, when you try to print it
3. x is again not defined when you try to call the function - `weight_for_binky(x)`
4. indentation is wrong, which may be result of poor formatting when you post your code.

```
    def weight_for_binky(weight):
        return weight * 0.38
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        weight = int(input("What do you weight? "))
        print(f"you weight {weight_for_binky(weight)} pounds.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that x is defined inside a function, and cannot be accessed outside of the function. You would either have to write code like this:

```
def weight_for_binky(x):
    #asking for weight
    weight = int(input("What do you weigh? "))
    #binky weight
    x = (weight * 0.38)
    print("you weigh " + str(x) + " pounds. \n")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    weight_for_binky(x)
```

or like this:

```
def weight_for_binky(x):
    #asking for weight
    weight = int(input("What do you weigh? "))
    #binky weight
    x = (weight * 0.38)
    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("you weigh " + str(weight_for_binky(x)) + " pounds. \n"))
```

Comment: You realise that x is still not defined in `weight_for_binky(x)`, right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm Python fan and here is my solution:

```
def weight_for_binky(x):
    weight = float(input("What do you weigh? "))
    x = (weight * 0.38)
    return f'you weigh {x} pounds. \n'


weight = weight_for_binky(x=1)
print(weight)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    weight
```

I suggest using `float` function because a user may enter he/she is 20.5 (my metric system unit is not pounds so the number is not real) your program returns error.

And also you should have indented `print` statement in the function.

Comment: what do you think your last line is doing?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'm studying the last call but I'm still trying to figure out how it works :) I'll study more and tell you if I got it.

Comment: how would I add a second variable such as y? so y = (weight * 2.5) ?

Comment: I will modify my answer. Please describe more what you want. I can add an `if` statement for you if input is between for example `a and b`, calculate X, else calculate Y. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

In Python you don't have brackets for **defining code blocks**, so using a correct **indentation** is very important. 
Also in this case pass to the function a variable `x` it's quite useless*(also in your case x it's not defined)*, you can do like this:

```
def weight_for_binky():
#asking for weight
  weight = int(input("What do you weigh? "))
#binky weight
  return (weight * 0.38)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  x = weight_for_binky()
  print("you weigh " + str(x) + " pounds. \n")
```